# Program crashes/stops after getting the last string or the last price in array based program

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors, crash

The program allows you to get the product's name and price by order, the data is stored in arrays and im using for loops to input and output the array elements, but when the user inputs the last product name or price the program stops working. Is it a compiler limitation or something with the code I'm waiting for your answers. I tested it in Code::Blocks and DevC++ IDEs.
In the link down below you have the code itself and an image of the program running.
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/17vWo0KY5xVqAPK3tsgbo0X-wOTc_FjQr/view?usp=sharing]

[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGsNp.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i , n  , j;
    cout<<"Input the number of the products: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    string Product [n];
    double Price[n];
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){

cout<< "Input the name of product"<<i<<" :"<<endl;
        cin>>Product[i];
        cout<<"Input the price of product "<<i<<" :"<<endl;
        cin>>Price[i];

    }

    for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
        cout<< "Product "<<Product[i]<<" costs: "<< Price[i]<<" $."<< endl;



}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read about array indexing in your favourite C++ book. It should be covered at the very beginning of the introduction to arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array index starts from 0 to n-1. Here when you are taking input you are trying to store the value of Price and Product at nth index which is not possible. So instead start for loop from 0 or instead of storing in ith index sore in i-1 index.

Initial Loop:

> `for(i=1;i<=n;i++){  /* some code*/ }
>
> for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
>           /* some code*/
>   }`

Updated for loop start from 0:

> `for(i=0; i<n; i++){
>    /* some code*/
>   }`
>
> `for(j=0; j<n; j++){
>           cout<< "Product "<<Product[j]<<" costs: "<< Price[j]<<" $."<< endl;
>   }`

also there is alternate use :

> `for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
>
>           cout<< "Input the name of product"<<i<<" :"<<endl;
>           cin>>Product[i-1];
>           cout<<"Input the price of product "<<i<<" :"<<endl;
>           cin>>Price[i-1]; 
>   }`
>
> `for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
>           cout<< "Product "<<Product[j-1]<<" costs: "<< Price[j-1]<<" $."<< endl;  }`